# Is there anyway to implement a killswitch on ubuntu server running docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vpn

I am trying to implement a killswitch for the VPN (NordVPN) on a machine running Ubuntu server and a few docker containers. I have followed the online tutorial on "https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/how-to-make-a-vpn-kill-switch-in-linux-with-ufw/" but no matter how many times i try it does not work. I have tried a couple of other sites and youtube videos with similar suggestions and it still does not work. The strange thing is i have gotten this to work on the Raspberry PI4. Can any one guide me here?

I should probably clarify what i mean when i say "wont work". I mean that when i disable ufw i am able to ping 8.8.8.8 and when i enable it the ping times out.

**UFW Config**

```
ufw allow in to 192.168.0.180/24
ufw allow out to 192.168.0.180/24
ufw allow in to 127.0.0.1/8
ufw allow in to 192.168.0.180/24
ufw allow in to 172.17.0.1/16
ufw allow in to 192.168.64.1/20
ufw allow in to 10.8.2.2/24
ufw allow out to 127.0.0.1/8
ufw allow out to 192.168.0.180/24
ufw allow out to 172.17.0.1/16
ufw allow out to 192.168.64.1/20
ufw allow out to 10.8.2.2/24
ufw default deny outgoing
ufw default deny incoming
ufw allow out to 194.32.235.142 port 1194 proto udp
ufw allow out on tun0 from any to any
ufw allow in on tun0 from any to any
```

```
root@caemlyn:/etc/ufw# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
192.168.0.0/24             ALLOW       Anywhere                  
127.0.0.0/8                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
172.17.0.0/16              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
192.168.64.0/20            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
10.8.2.0/24                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW       Anywhere                  

192.168.0.0/24             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
127.0.0.0/8                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
172.17.0.0/16              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
192.168.64.0/20            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
10.8.2.0/24                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
194.32.235.142 1194/udp    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
```

**Ifconfig output**

```
br-9cb1bdbbf84a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.64.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.79.255
        ether 02:42:9e:82:5e:51  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 211277  bytes 130656302 (130.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 352533  bytes 249366542 (249.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:9d:b3:d9:2c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.180  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 88:ae:dd:00:37:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 44600476  bytes 56372099057 (56.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 27845  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46383936  bytes 52331791760 (52.3 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2596151  bytes 1459406756 (1.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2596151  bytes 1459406756 (1.4 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.3
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 207  bytes 68311 (68.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 307  bytes 27430 (27.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth460b9ca: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 92:b1:de:ba:67:26  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 40870  bytes 72041915 (72.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 143637  bytes 86046662 (86.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth516019b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a6:a9:b9:2b:5e:2e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 569  bytes 896901 (896.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 97332  bytes 9600228 (9.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth5c44a7f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b6:43:53:c5:6d:0d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1807  bytes 4700169 (4.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63243  bytes 6634346 (6.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth65b7e72: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ca:4d:ac:4f:3f:38  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1683  bytes 7125453 (7.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 97020  bytes 9603548 (9.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth99a8582: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 42:77:5b:15:ce:65  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 75556  bytes 25040898 (25.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 213412  bytes 154364699 (154.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethc8ac704: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7a:9c:eb:9e:c4:7b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 88725  bytes 20218911 (20.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 186977  bytes 23282501 (23.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethecf7ea8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e6:b5:a7:b4:8c:83  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 252  bytes 1031463 (1.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 100190  bytes 9838296 (9.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 6c:94:66:54:e0:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```